# Sort and merge list based on another list

Tags: c#, linq

Here I'm merging a list to end of another list after sorting it according to another list.This should sort processdetails list according to the order in routeplans list if any item not present in processdetails list is found it should keep the order and add it to processdetails list. Simply saying it just merging two lists based on another list.The below code works fine, I want to know whether there is cleaner way of doing this.if possible in linq.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SortByList
{
public class OnGoingProcess
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var processDetails = new List<OnGoingProcess>();
        processDetails.Add(new OnGoingProcess() { Id = 120, Name = "Process 29", Code = "T20" });
        processDetails.Add(new OnGoingProcess() { Id = 100, Name = "Process 2", Code = "A20" });
        processDetails.Add(new OnGoingProcess() { Id = 99, Name = "Process 3", Code = "S20"  });
        processDetails.Add(new OnGoingProcess() { Id = 85, Name = "Process 229", Code = "B20" });
        processDetails.Add(new OnGoingProcess() { Id = 220, Name = "Process 39", Code = "C20" });
        processDetails.Add(new OnGoingProcess() { Id = 15, Name = "Process 20", Code = "D20" });
        processDetails.Add(new OnGoingProcess() { Id = 101, Name = "Process 129", Code = "G20" });

        var routePlans = new List<OnGoingProcess>();
        routePlans.Add(new OnGoingProcess() { Id = 100, Name = "Process 2" });
        routePlans.Add(new OnGoingProcess() { Id = 120, Name = "Process 29" });
        routePlans.Add(new OnGoingProcess() { Id = 222, Name = "Process new" });
        routePlans.Add(new OnGoingProcess() { Id = 85, Name = "Process 229" });
        routePlans.Add(new OnGoingProcess() { Id = 101, Name = "Process 129" });

        var sortedPlans = new List<OnGoingProcess>();

        foreach (var plan in routePlans)
        {
            var selectedDetails = processDetails.Where(x => x.Id == plan.Id).ToList();

            if (selectedDetails.Any())
            {
                sortedPlans.AddRange(selectedDetails);
                processDetails.RemoveAll(x => x.Id == plan.Id);

            }
            else
            {
                sortedPlans.Add(plan);
            }
        }
        processDetails.AddRange(sortedPlans);

        foreach (var sorted in processDetails)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id : " + sorted.Id + " Name : " + sorted.Name + " Code : " + sorted.Code );
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

     //Id : 99 Name : Process 3 Code : S20
     //Id : 220 Name : Process 39 Code : C20
     //Id : 15 Name : Process 20 Code : D20
     //Id : 100 Name : Process 2 Code : A20
     //Id : 120 Name : Process 29 Code : T20
     //Id : 222 Name : Process new Code :
     //Id : 85 Name : Process 229 Code : B20
     //Id : 101 Name : Process 129 Code : G20

    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: this question might better be suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to do it with LINQ, using this queries:

First order processDetails that are not in the `routePlans`:

```
var orderedFirst = processDetails.Where(x=>!routePlans.Any(r=>r.Id==x.Id));
```

then construct list of items to order, it  contains from not yet sorted processdetails and routeplans that are not in `processdetails`:

```
var toOrder = processDetails.Except(orderedFirst).ToList();
toOrder.AddRange(routePlans.Where(r=>!toOrder.Any(o=>o.Id==r.Id)));
```

than order this list on order in `routeplans`:

```
var orderedSecond = toOrder
              .OrderBy(x => routePlans.Select((t,i) => new {i, t.Id} )
                                      .First(t=>t.Id==x.Id)
                                      .i);
```

than merge two lists:

```
var result = orderedFirst.ToList();
result.AddRange(orderedSecond);
result.Dump();
```

Result is the same as  yours:

[image]

But linq queries not very pretty and readable.

Answer (score 3):

What are you doing is essentially a [full outer join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Full_outer_join_.28.E2.9F.97.29) which in LINQ can be efficiently implemented with [right antijoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29) combined with [left outer join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Left_outer_join_.28.E2.9F.95.29):

```
var result =
    (from pd in processDetails
     join rp in routePlans on pd.Id equals rp.Id into match
     where !match.Any()
     select pd)
     .Concat
     (from rp in routePlans
      join pd in processDetails on rp.Id equals pd.Id into match
      from pd in match.DefaultIfEmpty()
      select pd ?? rp)
     .ToList();
```